# $\ln x$ function for drawing ellipses

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, conic-sections, elliptic-functions

Hello dear mathematics enthusiasts,

last week, we saw general ellipse equation in the maths lesson.

Also an equation like $cx^{2}+dy^{2} = r^{2}$ is also usable, where equation forms like this.

[Shortened Equation Declaration here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnqbN.png)

Then I figured out that, $c$ is two times derivative of $-\ln a.$

[Proof $c$ is two times derivative of $-\ln a$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiOU3.png)

What I want to understand is, how can we draw ellipses using linear functions and their derivatives.

Sorry for misunderstood, 4th-grade senior high school student.

Comment: $c=1/a^2$= **(minus)** the second derivative of $ln(a)$ (take care of the minus sign) is not false in itself, but, sorry, it has no more interest than setting $c=sin(a)$ and being astonished at the coincidence with (minus)the  second derivative of $\sin(a)$. One thing is certain: it cannot be usable as a tool for drawing ellipses.

Comment: I've tried to emulate formula using a graph calculator (I use Desmos) and failed. I really want to test formula but I can't express it to the calculator.